# Make bing maps streetch all the may

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, wpf-4.0

How can I make that **bing maps** take all place below.

First row is name
Second row is last name:
Third name is map.

I want that bing maps takes everything from third row to all the way down.
Maps should be in column 1 and column 2

```
    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">First name:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Last name:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">name</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">name</TextBlock>
        <my:Map Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the row and column fill the rest of the container with "*"

Also use Grid.ColumnSpan="2" so that the map spans across two columns

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">First name:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Last name:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">name</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">name</TextBlock>
        <my:Map Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I didn't even know about this **boldGrid.ColumnSpan="2"**

I learned stomething new. What is different between Auto and *

Comment: Auto implies that it will reserve a space for the size of the element, hence if you haven't specified a size for that element, it will set the size of the container to the default/system size of that element. if you have specified a size, it will reserve the space for the defined size. The "*" on the other hand implies that it takes ALL the available space left after all other element container sizes is resolved.

Comment: Assuming ControlA is set to a height of 200 and ControlB does not have a height set, specifying <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> and   <RowDefinition Height="*"/> for a container that has a height of 1000 will reserve 200 for ControlA and 800 for ControlB.

Answer (score 0):

For a row to take up the remainder of space, you need to use the `"*"` `GridLength` setting for its `Height`:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">First name:</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Last name:</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">name</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">name</TextBlock>
    <my:Map Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

You can find out full details from the [`Grid` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.